# Ios add count of items in json file

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, ipad

Hi, I'm creating a JSON request with code below and its working perfectly:

```
for (int i=0; i<= [urls count]-1; i++) {
    self.items=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [self.items setObject:[names objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"results"];
    [self.items setObject:[urls objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"URL"];
    [self.list addObject:_soccerList];
}

NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:_list
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];

self.results=[NSJSONSerialization
                           JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                           options:0
                           error:&error];
```

But, I would like to add this header to the JSON request where I am adding count of the items.Any of you knows how can I do this?

```
{
"resultCount":50,
"results": [

/// json content 

]
}
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In for loop before line adding _soccerList,add the following line

```
 NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[self.items count],@"resultCount",nil];
 [self.list addObject:dic];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"50", @"resultCount", _list1, @"results", nil];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
```

Comment: @Juan If this answers your question, you should accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it!